# Stack not able to get scrolled when wrapped inside CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, stack, singlechildscrollview, customscrollview

## I'm using Custom scroll view over the stack to get a scrollable behaviour But it is not getting scrolled.

I've tried the approach Using single child scroll view But it was giving me an error of infinite size So I've switched to this approach My stack widgets are getting layered properly, but my overall stack is not getting scrolled. Below is my code.

````
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: colorScheme.background,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          // shrinkWrap: true,
          // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: true,
              child: Stack(children: [
                Image.asset('assets/images/demoProduct.png'),
                Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 50,
                  // bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35.w, vertical: 30),
                    // height: 900,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        color: Color(0xFFFFFBF8)),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 196.w,
                              child: Text(
                                'Bauhaus Enamel Colander Long Name',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.sp,
                                    fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                    color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '\$ 75.99',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 28.sp,
                                      fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                      color: Color(0xFF00373E),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '\$ 99.99',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.sp,
                                      fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                      color: Color(0xFF8E8E8E),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "By Darling Spring",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                            fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                            color: Color(0XFF4DA1A1),
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                              color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                              color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                              color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                              color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                              color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '(83)',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                                  fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                  color: Color(0xFF1D1F22),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Color',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.sp,
                              fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                              color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              ...List.generate(
                                palleteColors.length,
                                (index) => buildColorPallete(
                                  color: palleteColors[index],
                                  isSelected: _selectedColor == index,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedColor = index;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Size',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.sp,
                              fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                              color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            _buildSize(
                                title: 'S',
                                isSelected: _selectedSize == 0,
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedSize = 0;
                                  });
                                }),
                            _buildSize(
                                title: 'M',
                                isSelected: _selectedSize == 1,
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedSize = 1;
                                  });
                                }),
                            _buildSize(
                                title: 'L',
                                isSelected: _selectedSize == 2,
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedSize = 2;
                                  });
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Size Chart",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                            fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                            color: Color(0xFF00798C),
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Quantity',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.sp,
                              fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                              color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            CupertinoButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                    )),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.remove,
                                  color: Color(
                                    0xFF4B4B4,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );```

**Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here I've wrapped this custom scroll view with a single child scroll view, even but I'm getting a multiple errors on that approach. I just need the stack elements to get screwed just like a column wrapped with a single child scroll view.  **
**I've tried using single child scroll view, but it was giving me an error of infinite size Search switched to another approach using the custom scroll view. I've wrapped my stack in it Under the sliver filled remaining widget But still my stack widget is not getting scrolled Just let me know what else can I do. I'm expecting a solution that helped me to scroll this stack widget just like a column wrapped under a single child scroll view. Just let me know if you need any other additional information to answer this question.**
````

Answer (score 0):

I have remove some of your custom widgets in order for me to be able to test and debug, but the issue your having is with the `SliverFillRemaining` widget this widget will fill the rest of the screen or let's say occupy the full height of the screen then when you set `hasScrollBody` to `true` (by default is true anyway) you essentially tell the widget that fill my screen but there is a position of my child widget that is is scrollable so in your case you should have wrap stack with `SingleChildScrollView` so that if stack has more height that the screen height it should scroll, look at the example below i have added a container with a 2x screen size height inside a stack then

```dart
Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/images/demoProduct.png'),
                    Positioned(
                      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 50,
                      // bottom: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35, vertical: 30),
                        // height: 900,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0xFFFFFBF8)),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 196,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Bauhaus Enamel Colander Long Name',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                        color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      '\$ 75.99',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 28,
                                          fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                          color: Color(0xFF00373E),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '\$ 99.99',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                          color: Color(0xFF8E8E8E),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "By Darling Spring",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                color: Color(0XFF4DA1A1),
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                  color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                  color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                  color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                  color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                  color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '(83)',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                      color: Color(0xFF1D1F22),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Color',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                  color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 15,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Size',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                  color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            ),

                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Size Chart",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                color: Color(0xFF00798C),
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Quantity',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                  color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                CupertinoButton(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        border: Border.all(
                                          color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                        )),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.remove,
                                      color: Color(
                                        0xFF4B4B4,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*2,)
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

so now it scroll as it should another approach you could just use `SliverToBoxAdapter` but this time there is no need of using the `SingleChildScrollView` widget since the scrolling will be taking care of by `CustomScrollView` widget here is an example of the code

```dart
Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/demoProduct.png'),
                  Positioned(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 50,
                    // bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35, vertical: 30),
                      // height: 900,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          color: Color(0xFFFFFBF8)),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 196,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Bauhaus Enamel Colander Long Name',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                      color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '\$ 75.99',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 28,
                                        fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                        color: Color(0xFF00373E),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '\$ 99.99',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                        color: Color(0xFF8E8E8E),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "By Darling Spring",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                              color: Color(0XFF4DA1A1),
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.star_rate_rounded,
                                color: Color(0XFFC7B661),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '(83)',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                    color: Color(0xFF1D1F22),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Color',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Size',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Size Chart",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                              color: Color(0xFF00798C),
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Quantity',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontFamily: 'Mulish',
                                color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              CupertinoButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                                      )),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.remove,
                                    color: Color(
                                      0xFF4B4B4,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3)),height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*2,)
                ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

so in both ways the the stack is scrollable, choose what suite the most.
I hope it helps :D Kudos